# Ethernet falls back from 1 Gbps to 100 Mbps randomly

Tags: networking, router, network-adapter, speed, windows-networking

I am on Windows 10.0.19045, 22H2. Motherboard has Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller. Router is ASUS RT-AC66U. Both network interface and router are 1 Gbps capable. Connection is a wired ethernet cable.

Periodically, the Realtek interface will fall back to 100 Mbps.

What might cause this to occur? What, if anything, would prevent it from occurring?

Comment: “What might cause this to occur? What, if anything, would prevent it from occurring?” Most likely a flaky Ethernet cable or Ethernet connection on the cable. The wind blows or an Ethernet cable moves slightly and the connection speed drops.

Comment: More often than not this is a cable or connector issue. Either the cable is poor quality or has breaks that depend on how the cable or connector has shifted. Also don't route ethernet cables next to mains cables as interference can cause issues.

Comment: 100Mbps Ethernet (100BASE-T) requires 4 wires (2 twisted pairs). Gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE-T) requires 8 wires (4 twisted pairs). So when you end up doing 100Mbps when you thought you should be able to do gigabit, the first thing to look at is if you have a flaky connection on the two pairs that 1000BASE-T needs that 100BASE-T doesn't. That is, pins 4&5, and pins 7&8, so the blue pair and the brown pair. But don't just inspect the wires; inspect the connector pins too, or even a cracked solder joint where an 8P8C female socket connects to a circuitboard.